# Angular2 modules root modules import fails

Tags: angular, typescript

I have three modules

```
Appmodule, usersmodule and safetymodule
```

The appmodule is the root module whereby i have imported both users and safety modules as

am also using primeng2 contextmenu which requires that i import

```
ContextMenuModule
```

The problem comes in the users module where i have to import the context module again and yet ive already imported it in the app module as shown below

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   FormsModule,
   DashboardModule,
   SafetyModule,
   ContextMenuModule, //added this here
   UsersModule,
 ],
 exports: [BrowserModule,ToastyModule,SlimLoadingBarModule,ContextMenuModule],

 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
export class AppModule { }
```

In the users module when i fail to import the ContextModule an error is thrown

Where am i going wrong since by having to import modules in every module is rather alot of duplication which i believe angular2 ngModule is supposed to solve

What else do i need to add

UPDATE
this is the way am adding the context menu

```
   <p-contextMenu  #cm [model]="menuitems"></p-contextMenu>
```

The error which result when i fail to import ContextMenu in usersmodule is:

```
If 'p-contextMenu' is an Angular component and it has 'model' input
 , then verify that it is part of this module.
```

The error is cleared when i import contextmenu in users module but am much worried about the code duplication for the imported modules

Comment: can you share what the error is?

Comment: Ive added the error

Comment: That's a useful tidbit of information. The op is referring to an existing module: http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/contextmenu

Comment: Yes it pretty annoying having to duplicate all these existing modules all over in all modules it defeats the real essence of modularity in angular2

Comment: You could export the ContextMenuModule module from your AppModule, but not sure if you want your users to have access to the entire module.

Comment: Ive added contextmenumodule in exports like this exports:[ContextMenuModule] but still doesnt work, how do i export it

Comment: Ive updated the question with the export